# Can a browser extension download a ready-to-use IndexedDB database?

Tags: indexeddb, browser-extension

I want to create a browser extension (Chrome, Firefox) that uses a large database (~1 million entries). Because the extension will use the data very frequently, it has to be downloaded to the client.

I read that it is possible to download JSON files from a server and then add it to a IndexedDB. But this will take a lot of time for a large db. Since the browser extension will only read the data and never alter it, I would like to know if it is possible for the extension to download a ready-to-use IndexedDB from a server. So the server would create the db and the clients would only have to download it and could use it instantly.

Or is there a completely different way to give a browser extension access to a large database without having to access a remote db every time?

Comment: Is it going to use all one million entries "very frequently", or could you simply keep a cache for the most frequently used data? You could even make the cache entries never expire, so you effectively build the local database as you go, in exchange for slower initial requests. The ability to rebuild, refresh or restructure the data is useful generally, even if you're sure now that the data for existing entries won't change.

Comment: You could think of it as a spellchecker that checks all web pages for spelling errors or a filter program that checks all links on web sites and filters out the ones not suitable for children. So it could use a cache, but still would have to make hundreds of db requests for every page request.

Comment: If you're going to be making an extension that filters a very large amount of URLs, you can use a [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) to improve both storage and performance considerably. This could reduce the physical hit ratio to the point where a "physical lookup" (i.e. a cache hit) is sufficiently rare that it doesn't matter that it has to go online. (Still not a direct answer to your question, I know.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download an "indexedDB database", as you refer to it. There is no such thing. How data is stored in indexedDb, in terms of the actual files and data format in each file, is not a part of the indexedDb API. It is not intended to be accessed in this manner.

What you can do, is download data using a transferable format. A very well supported and common format to use in this case is JSON. JSON is a great format for downloading data.

Consider writing a program that creates the JSON response on the server. The browser extension can then download the JSON file(s) and then create objects in the indexedDb database in the browser in the context associated with the browser extension. In other words, export the data from the database on the server to JSON, transfer the json file or files or response bodies over HTTP, and then import the json into indexedDb. This is a very routine program design, regardless of the size of the data.

When using an extension, such as Chrome extension, you can specify that you want unlimited data size, and you will get something that is "almost" unlimited, up to some percentage of your computer's storage capacity (hard drive size).